# Only inserting single row into a table using mysqli inside a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach

I'm having trouble inserting multiple rows into a table called bookedseattbl. I'm using a foreach loop but it is only inserting one row. The first insert query executes fine.

```
<?php
$seats=explode(',',$_SESSION['seats']);
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO bookingtbl(UserId, DetailsId, Amount, PaymentStatus) VALUES ('$uid', (SELECT detailstbl.DetailsId FROMdetailstbl
                    JOIN movietbl ON detailstbl.MovieId=movietbl.id AND movietbl.id = '$movieid'
                    JOIN theatretbl ON detailstbl.TheatreId=theatretbl.TheatreId AND theatretbl.TheatreName LIKE '$theatre%'
                    JOIN timingtbl ON timingtbl.TimingId=detailstbl.TimingId AND timingtbl.Time = '$time'),'$amt',1)");
$a=mysqli_insert_id($con);
foreach ($seats as $x)
{
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO bookedseattbl(BookingId, SeatId) VALUES ('$a', (SELECT * FROM seatstbl WHERE SeatNo='$x')))");
}
?>
```

If I try putting an absolute value inplace of the select query, it executes as expected but only executes once when using the select query.

Comment: Could it be that `BookingId` is a unique key in your database?

Comment: If your loop query only inserts once, the (1) does `$seats`have more than 1 value, or (2) is there a `PRIMARY`/`UNIQUE` Key on your `BookingId` column?

Comment: BookingId is an autoincrement primary key value I get from the first insert query that I try to then insert into the second table.

$seats has more than 1 value. Leaving the loop as is and putting absolute values into the SeatId executes the correct number of iterations

Comment: Did you manage to get a solution? I have the same problem.